# deleting 'e' when it is word final

Tags: prolog

can anyone help me delete the final 'e' of a list?
I have a data set:

```
lemma([c,h,a,s,e],[vb,t]).
lemma([e,a,t],[vb,t]).
lemma([l,i,k,e],[vb,t]).
lemma([d,i,e],[vb,i]).
lemma([s,n,e,e,z,e],[vb,i]).
```

and my code is:

```
q0(Token,[vb,_]) :-
   lemma(Lemma,[vb,_]),
   delete_last(Lemma,New_Lemma),
   suffix(Sff),
   append(New_Lemma,Sff,Token).

delete_last(Lemma,New_Lemma) :-
   append(New_Lemma,[_],Lemma).

suffix([e,r]).
```

My code so far deletes the the last element of a list which is fine for any lemma in the data base except for the lemma [e,a,t]. How would I make Prolog understand to only delete 'e' when its word final?

Any suggestion to help me start this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: delete_last(Lemma,New_Lemma) :- append(New_Lemma,[e],Lemma).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have tried inserting [e] in place of [_] however that creates another problem because then the code does not produce [e,a,t,er] rather it leaves [e,a,t,e,r] out of the set of possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition, *eliding* lemma' last with suffix' first

```
q0(Token,[vb,_]) :-
   lemma(Lemma,[vb,_]),
   suffix([X|Xs]),
   (  last(Lemma, X)
   -> append(Lemma, Xs, Token)
   ;  append(Lemma, [X|Xs], Token)
   ).
```

test

```
?- q0(T, [vb,_]).
T = [c, h, a, s, e, r] ;
T = [e, a, t, e, r] ;
T = [l, i, k, e, r] ;
T = [d, i, e, r] ;
T = [s, n, e, e, z, e, r].
```